# Playing a jquery cycle slideshow on click, then pausing after a delay

Tags: jquery, delay, cycle

I'm using the jQuery Cycle plugin to create a text "scrambler": the "cycler" div loads with a single text sentence, which doesn't change. Then on clicking a button, the text should (a) rapidly cycle through all the other text strings and (b) stop automatically after 1 second on a different (random) text string. Clicking the button again should repeat the effect, each time coming to rest on a different snippet of text.

Here is my code. I am avoiding `autostop` and `autostopcount`, since I believe "stopping" in Cycle's terms destroys the instance of the slideshow and doesn't easily allow re-starting. I think I just want to pause and resume the slideshow

```
    // Configure cycle slideshow
    $('#cycler').cycle({
        fx: 'none', 
        speed:  '1',
        timeout: '10',
        random:1,
    }).cycle('pause'); // Pause the slideshow immediately
```

I can configure a dummy link to manually pause/resume the slideshow on each click with no problems:

```
    // Toggle slideshow when clicking button
    $('#cycler-switch').click(function(){
        $('#cycler').cycle('toggle');
        return false;
        });
```

But since I want to pause the slideshow automatically, 1 second after the button being clicked, I changed the above code to the following:

```
    // Play then Pause 
    $('#cycler-switch').click(function(){
        $('#cycler').cycle('toggle').delay(1000).cycle('toggle');
        return false;
        });
```

Unfortunately this has the effect that the slideshow won't even start playing on click.

Any ideas? Should I be using setTimeout instead of .delay() for some reason? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not to answer the question, but get rid of the comma after

```
random:1,
```

IE will throw a fit!